# Chrome console keeps getting stuck in a quirky state

Tags: google-chrome, console, indexeddb

The console gets stuck in a state where every two page refreshes a new closed instance of my indexedDB is displayed. They are all closed except for the one on the top and everything within the application still seems to function normally, however other strange things occur when using the console.

1. When I click on a table within the database it shows the data, but when I try to filter or go to the next page it all disappears. I have to completely close the browser tab and then reload.
2. Sometimes when I enter in console commands they don't do anything, don't return anything (not even undefined), but when I refresh the page it alternative between working and not working.

[image]

Let me know if you need some more information. I haven't a clue what's causing this. I'm using the latest version of Chrome 35. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saw this once. Try a fresh install, and if that does not work, try upgrading to dev channel 37. I did both those things (for other reasons), but have not been able to reproduce the bug since. Trudging through Chromium's list of open issues or changes might also help.

Also, it looks like your question is not really about programming so it might be closed. There are other 'something.overflow' sites to post this type question.

Edit: also, regarding the disappearing issue, I actually reported this bug on Chromium. It was recently fixed!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll give it a try. I was thinking it was programming related and had something to do with something I was doing wrong with indexedDB, though I basically followed examples from mdn.

Comment: The MDN examples are good, except for how most of them try to use a global variable to reference the database connection. Do not do that.

Comment: Nope, definitely didn't do that. I made a class that holds the connection information. Anyways, upgrading to the latest beta did solve the problem.