# Chrome Developer Tools IndexDb filter - items disappear

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, indexeddb

Working with Chrome version 35.0.1916.153 m , when I open Resources/IndexedDB and I select a table, all the items appear properly, but as soon as I write something in the input search box the items disappear from the list.

The items are not removed from the IndexDB, but to see them again I need to restart Chrome.

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome console keeps getting stuck in a quirky state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353594/chrome-console-keeps-getting-stuck-in-a-quirky-state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- See probable duplicate [Chrome console keeps getting stuck in a quirky state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353594).
- See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=379483 for insight.
- The problem was fixed in a newer version of Chrome, but it is likely that the stable(?) version you are using has not received the update yet.

Comment: You're right. With that title I didn't found it. Should I maintain this question or remove it?

Comment: You do not have to do anything. Glad I helped. Always feel free to ask your questions!