# IndexedDB : upgrade and success events got stuck while creating or removing dynamic object stores in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, google-chrome, indexeddb

Want to create and remove dynamic amount of object stores in IndexedDB as per Application requirement. Everything is working fine in IE. :)
Chrome also fine, but very first time data is not populating on the screen.

I have tried below code. `updateStore` function will be called for dynamic object stores creation / deletion.
`newStores` - array of new store details, `removedStores` - array of delete store details.

```
...
...
updateStore: function(newStores,removedStores) {
            if(db){
                db.close();
                db = null;
                dbPromise = null;
                process();
            } else {
                process();
            }

            function process() {
                console.log("In process function");
                var dbReq, deferred;
                deferred = $q.defer();
                dbReq = indexedDB.open(dbName, parseInt(++dbVersion) || 1);
                dbReq.onsuccess = function() {
                    console.log("In success event");
                    db = dbReq.result;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        deferred.resolve(db);
                    });
                };
                dbReq.onblocked = dbReq.onerror = rejectWithError(deferred);
                dbReq.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
                    console.log("In upgrade event");
                    var tx;
                    db = event.target.result;
                    tx = event.target.transaction;
                    $log.log("$indexedDB: Upgrading database '" + db.name + "' from version " + event.oldVersion + " to version " + event.newVersion + " ...");

                    if(newStores) {
                        for(var i=0;i<newStores.length;i++) {
                            var storeName = newStores[i].name;
                            var storeDetails = newStores[i].details;
                            db.createObjectStore(storeName, storeDetails);
                        }
                    }
                    if(removedStores) {
                        for(var i=0;i<removedStores.length;i++) {
                            var storeName = removedStores[i].name;
                            db.deleteObjectStore(storeName);
                        }
                    }
                    applyNeededUpgrades(event.oldVersion, event, db, tx, $log);
                };
               return deferred.promise;
            }
          }
...
...
```

**Appln Desc:** If the user authentication successful, dynamic amount of object stores created and data dumped into it. Once done, it will redirected to home page, they can able to add/delete object stores.

**Problem Desc:** 
If the user wont create or delete existing stores means, the data is populating on the screen without any issues.
When the user create new store and navigating screens means, data is not populating. In this time, if we open Developer Tool in chrome means, data's are populated. And also another one important thing, here after data is populating fine while another set of new stores.

[image]

While creating dynamic stores, the control goes to inside `process` function and prints message. But upgrade and success events are got stuck. So data's are not populating on the screen.
In this time, if we open chrome Developer tool means, it got resumed and data's are populated on screen also.

[image]

It indicates chrome needs to refresh IndexedDB in first time (IE is fine). And also i didnt see any issue while creating second time and so on. If i didnt refresh (mean opening Developer tool), DB has crashed. I dont know what i did wrong.

Is there any native method available to refresh the database in IndexedDB.

Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a runnable self-contained snippet of code that demonstrates the problem. Your snippet above doesn't run on its own.

Comment: Try logging the onerror and onblock handler it's possible you are getting an error or you are blocked because the db is still in upgrade mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Developer Tools IndexDb filter - items disappear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364917/chrome-developer-tools-indexdb-filter-items-disappear)